# LINQ join based on checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 in a C# WPF app. I have this query to search the Employee entity:

```
var query = Context.Employees.AsQueryable();
switch (selectedColumnValue)
{
    case "lastName":
        query = query.Where(q => q.lastName == SearchValue);
        break;
    case "employeeID":
        query = query.Where(q => q.personnelID == SearchValue);
        break;
    case "securityID":
        query = query.Where(q => q.securityID == SearchValue);
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
```

The parent entity `Employee` may have some child rows in the `EmployeeStatus` entity to indicate if the employee is inactive, on leave of absence, or archived. `Employee` entity's primary key is `employeeID` and is a foreign key on `EmployeeStatus`.

Here is the Employee entity's columns:

```
public int employeeID { get; set; }
public string personnelID { get; set; }
public string securityID { get; set; }
public string firstName { get; set; }
public string middleName { get; set; }
public string lastName { get; set; }
public string suffix { get; set; }
public string job { get; set; }
public string organizationalUnit { get; set; }
public string costCenter { get; set; }
public string notes { get; set; }
public System.DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
```

And here's the EmployeeStatus entity's columns

```
public int employeeStatusID { get; set; }
public int employeeID { get; set; }
public int validEmployeeStatusID { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> exitDate { get; set; }
public System.DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
```

If the user clicks the checkbox "Include archived employees?" during the search, we need to do the join to the `EmployeeStatus` and add the condition that the `EmployeeStatus` column `validEmployeeStatusID` equals `5` (Archived). How do you do this in LINQ?

**Update**: I need to add the Linq join after the above `switch` statement in an IF statement, such as this:

```
if (IncludeArchived)
{
   // Add to Linq query here using method syntax
}
```

And so the Linq statement needs to use the method syntax.

Comment: can you not use the `.Join() function or .Concat()` have you tried that..?

Comment: Thanks, @MethodMan. Would the `.Join()` just go at the end of the query after it's been built using the `Where()` clause?

Comment: If you're using EF you should have a navigational property on the Employee for EmployeeStatus

Comment: It would be much easier if you create and use **navigation properties**. EF will create the necessary joins for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'd never heard of Navigation Properties in EF. Always wondered what those `virtual` properties were.

Comment: Other than that, yes, you can use `Join` after `Where`, although it would be simpler to add another `Where` with `Any` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this query?

```
query = (from empl in query
         join status in Context.Status on empl.employeeID equals status.employeeID
         where status.employeeStatusID == 5
         select empl).Distinct();
```

Or you can perform chain:

```
query = query.Join(Context.Status, x => x.employeeID, x => x.employeeID, (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .Where(x => x.b.employeeStatusID == 5).Select(x => x.a).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks, @SlavaUtesinov. Notice in my question I'm using the method syntax to build the query and can't use your example code. I will need to add the join after the `switch` statement in an `if`. Please see my update above.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it. Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks, @SlavaUtesinov. A question: what is the `(a, b)` section doing? How does that work? Sorry, I'm new to Linq.

Comment: After join operation you should specify what fields do you need to remain from join result: `a` - is `query` part(Employee) and `b` - is EmployeeStatus part and result will contain both: `a` and `b`, i.e. `new { a, b }`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not *need* to add it after the switch statement.

In your current implementation you are including ALL employees (even the archived ones). So you actually need to make it so that you exclude the archived ones if the checkbox is not checked.

Note: I am assuming you have the navigation properties for your entities.

```
var query = Context.Employees.AsQueryable();

if (!IncludeArchived)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.Status == null || e.Status.employeeStatusId != 5);
}

switch (selectedColumnValue)
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @JanneMatikainen. Only some employees will have a record on the EmployeeStatus table -- the ones that are inactive, leave of absence, or archived. And yes, Visual Studio automatically generated the navigation properties when EF ran through the database-first generation of the models.

Comment: Okay, then you should maybe check that the status is null or the id on the status equals to 5. Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe I don't have the nav properties after all -- it won't let me use the `e.Status.employeeStatusId != 5`. It says `'ICollection<Status>' does not contain a definition for 'employeeStatusID'`

Comment: It might be EmployeeStatus. As you have EmployeeStatusID.